# AVFoundation can play one MJPEG AVI but not another

Tags: avfoundation, avi, mjpeg

AVFoundation is capable of playing this video:

```
[avi @ 0x7fade1002a00] non-interleaved AVI
Stream #0:0: Video:
    mjpeg (MJPG / 0x47504A4D),
    yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown),
    640x480,
    4779 kb/s,
    25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
```

But not this one:

```
Stream #0:0: Video:
    mjpeg (MJPG / 0x47504A4D),
    gray(bt470bg/unknown/unknown),
    400x960 [SAR 1:1 DAR 5:12],
    8 fps, 8 tbr, 8 tbn, 8 tbc
```

I believe the first video is color and the second is greyscale. The second seems to specify a different display aspect ratio.

Which factor is relevant to whether AVFoundation can play the video?